# Tooltip for 'cite' option missing

Tags: feature-request, tooltips

On some sites with MathJax support (looks like only on Mathoverflow and Maths, maybe others), when hovering over the words 'share', 'edit', 'close', 'delete', 'flag', a tooltip appears explaining what the purpose of each is for. For example, the word 'edit', when hovered over, says: "revise and improvise post".

> [image]

However, when highlighting 'cite', nothing happens.

[image]

It seems that title text for it is missing.

Comment: @nicael I don't know if it's particular to just Math.SE or other sites.  But this is the first time I've seen it and I still don't know what it does.

Comment: Some beta feature I guess, get an upvote for discovering.

Comment: [It's a site setting that's only enabled on a few sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293386/335251) I'm guessing that's why it doesn't have a tooltip.

Comment: @V2Blast holy necro.  finally nice to get an answer 8 years later though :)