# How does one cite an answer in MLA?

Tags: support, answers, citation

I used an answer from https://crypto.stackexchange.com and the links that were provided in the answer. Now, I am presenting the project for which I used the answer, and I would like to give proper attribution. From what I see, Crypto Stack Exchange does not give an option to cite the answer. How does one cite an answer in MLA format?

**Edit**

I am submitting my project for a science fair, and there is no one that I can ask about citations.

Comment: Its been years since I was in academia - but isn't there a standard for websites in general? Or do you mean stuff like author citations for pseudonymous users

Comment: Citing the Stack Exchange site wouldn’t make sense

Comment: That's not what Journeyman meant. He means that there are general rules on you refer to a website as a source. For example a link to the specific site you're quoting from and the date when you've accessed it. SE then has additional rules in regard of  "attribution required", like naming the author of the post you're quoting, meaning the username. So you should first ask your teacher how it should like, he or she knows what your school expects from you.

Comment: Some sites do have a "cite" button on posts, so it's not unheard of. I imagine there might be a user script to enable it on all sites. In the meantime, though, you can go to a site that does support it and copy the format from there.

Comment: Take a look at [this QA on Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/73666/56594). Maybe, Academia has even closer matches.

Comment: I've seen some citation questions asked on Writing SE, I believe. If you look for SE in Google scholar, you'll find loads of publications citing this site. I guess you'd simply need to find one using MLA.

Comment: @curious that’s a good idea. I’ll try that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How come not all Stack Exchange sites have the cite option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293384/how-come-not-all-stack-exchange-sites-have-the-cite-option) - that shows what it would look like if the option were available (so, copy that style), and why it's not always available (vote there, and on child meta (with a new question if necessary)).

Comment: @Rob That's related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: @Rob Meh, no need; the author self-closed the question, and flagging things for reopening is frowned upon.

Comment: Marvin, An appropriate [Q&A to upvote](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/61334) for adding *cite* to crypto.se, see also:  https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/469/61334