# I want to use content from a Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange question and answer. How do I comply with the Attribution requirements?

Tags: discussion, licensing, copyright, attribution, creative-commons

One of the requirements of the [CC BY-SA license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing) used for content on the Network is Attribution. What does proper attribution look like for questions and answers found on the Network?

Answer (score 6):

## The Requirements

The full requirements for attribution can be found in [Section 4 of CC BY-SA 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/legalcode.en), [Section 4 of CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode.en#restrictions), and [Section 3(a) of CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode.en#s3). The Creative Commons also has [a comparison chart for the attribution requirements across different versions of their licenses](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Detailed_attribution_comparison_chart).

The minimum requirements are very similar across the three versions of CC BY-SA in use on the Network:

- **Author's name or pseudonym.** [Credit to other parties](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Credit_to_others_explicit), such as editors or the collective body maintaining the work, is required if asked for in a reasonable manner. You do not need to list all editors, especially if it's unreasonable, but can identify the collective group. [Stack Overflow does ask that an indication that the content is from a Network site is visually included.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required) [The post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post/342316#342316) can be used to see editors and their edits.
- **Copyright notices**, if supplied. Network posts do not typically contain additional copyright notices.
- **Title**, if supplied. Questions typically have titles. Answers do not.
- **License**. A notice that refers to the Creative Commons license the work is made available under. This includes the specific version of the license. A URI or link to the license must be provided. [The post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post/342316#342316) can be used to view information about the license at any point in the post's history.
- **Warranties**, if supplied. Network posts do not typically contain an warranties from the licensor.
- **URI or link** to the material. This is a link to the specific post being attributed. It is a good idea to link to the specific version of the post being attributed. *TODO: Find a Help Center or Meta post that explains how to link to a specific version of a post.*
- **Indication of modification** and an indication of previous modifications, if applicable. Required by 4.0, required for adaptations by 3.0, and not required in 2.5.

---

## Recommended Practices

The Creative Commons has [recommended practices for attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Recommended_practices_for_attribution). For CC BY-SA 3.0 and CC BY-SA 4.0 licensed works, it is required avoid giving the impression that the author, editors, and publishers of the content endorse your work, but this is a good practice for CC BY-SA 2.5 licensed work as well.

Some examples of attribution for Network posts that meet these recommended practices for attribution and would be considered great attributions:

> ["A Terms of Service update restricting companies that scrape your profile information without your permission"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/277369/22) by [Jaydles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles) posted on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is licensed under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).

Because there are a large number of editors to the post, it is not likely to be considered reasonable to name all of the editors. However, it does mention the publication - the Network site - where the content was found.

> [Answer to "Why is 80 characters the 'standard' limit for code width?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/148678/2) by [Oded](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4767/oded), edited by [gnat](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat) and posted on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

In this example, there is only the author and one editor. In cases with a small number of editors, it would be reasonable to include all of the editors who contributed to the version of the work being attributed.

> Answer to "Why is 80 characters the 'standard' limit for code width?" [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/148678/2] by Oded, edited by gnat and posted on Software Engineering Stack Exchange is licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 [https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/].

In some cases, it may not be reasonable to provide hyperlinks. Perhaps the medium is one where a person cannot click on them - a document intended for printing, a slideshow where the slides will not be made available electronically, a video. In these cases, the URI to the content and the license must be given. URIs to profiles or the host are not required, but may be offered if reasonable.

> Post [https://pm.stackexchange.com/revisions/2766/4] by Eric Willeke, edited by Mark Robinson, mattdm, and callmekatootie and posted on Project Management Stack Exchange is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0 [https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/].

Because answers don't have titles, you don't need to fall back to the question title. Using the term "post by" or "answer by" and providing a hyperlink or URI is sufficient.

Do note that these are all great attributions. There may be other, minimally acceptable, attribution formats that meet the license requirements.

---

## Closing Thoughts

Keep in mind that each post on the Network is a separate work. If you are copying, redistributing, remixing, transforming, adapting, or building upon multiple posts, each post (question or answer) should be attributed independently. That is, a separate attribution should clearly appear for each post that you use.

It should also be noted that attributing a work is different than citing a work. If you are not copying, redistributing, remixing, transforming, adapting, or building upon the material, but were inspired by it, the work should be [cited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation). A standard citation for web-based content include the name of the author(s), the publication (site) title, the article title, a URI, and the date of access. [Some sites in the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293384/how-come-not-all-stack-exchange-sites-have-the-cite-option) have a feature that allows users to generate citations.

Comment: Personally [I use a different format](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10914).

Comment: Doesn't (proper) ***author*** attribution include ***a link*** to the user profile (on the same site as the post)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum No. The company does _ask_ that you do it. However, they can't place additional terms on the license. The only place what they ask is applicable is as an attribution party. It's probably a good practice to link to the profile, but it could also be unreasonable to provide URIs to multiple user profiles.